# Cómo hago para que haya padding en todas las columnas y filas en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, framework, documentacion

Lancé una exhibición de arte virtual internacional pero hay un problema al presentar los cuadros, resulta que muestra padding entre la primera fila y la segunda pero luego ya no sigue teniendo los mismos atributos porque se ve todo unido, quisiera que estuviera todo prolijo.  Acá está mi sitio web: https://brainish.art/gallery/ por favor ayúdenme, es bootstrap.

Comment: tenes cajas a las que le falta "mb-5", lo estoy viendo con el inspector de chrome. (es problema de margin, no de padding)

Comment: He actualizado el código y aún sigue el mismo problema cuando se ve desde un navegador de escritorio. Aunque sí solucionó el problema desde móvil.

Comment: los primeros 6 se muestran bien, luego ya se muestran sin margen o padding

Comment: Estas aplicando la clase mb-lg-0 en algunos casos y la clase mb-md-0 en otros, lo que te está estropeando los márgenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me han ayudado a resolver el problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando. Un enlace a otro lugar no ayuda a conservar la información de la pregunta pues puede ser modificado. Por otro lado, si ya ha sido resuelta y nadie ha puesto una respuesta completa que puedas aceptar, yo optaria por eliminar la pregunta.